# List Instances for higher-kinded types

Tags: haskell, typeclass

If I have a MultiParamTypeClass, say `Dictionary a k v` (whatever, it's kind is `* -> * -> *`) and I would like to make an instance for lists (ie `[(k,v)]`), is that possible?

I get that the compiler is complaining that that `[(k,v)]` is only kind `*` but is is possible to make this list (in this example an association list) behave like `Pair k v` but still being able to use Haskell's list type?

In code,

```
class Dictionary a where
    method :: Thing k v -> a k v
```

I'd like to form

```
instance Dictionary [(k,v)] where
    method = ...
```

Can that be done? I realize there is the OverloadedLists extension but I would like something that works on things more than literals.

Comment: Can you not make like `type Dict k v = [(k,v)]` and then `instance Dictionary Dict where...`?

Comment: @Redu I did try that but the compiler saw right through my naive attempt at being cunning. A newtype is of course something you can make new instances for, but here I'm trying to get the behaviour applied to lists.

Comment: You need some sort of type-level composition, since what you really want is (abusing notation a bit) is an instance for `([] .) . (,)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can change your type class to be indexed by the fully applied dictionary type, instead of a type constructor `* -> * ->  *`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances #-}

class Dictionary d where
  type Key d :: Type
  type Value d :: Type
  f :: Thing (Key d) (Value d) -> d

instance Dictionary [(k, v)] where
  type Key [(k, v)] = k
  type Value [(k, v)] = v
  f = ...

instance Dictionary (Map k v) where
  type Key (Map k v) = k
  type Value (Map k v) = v
  f = ...
```

Comment: that's a _really_ clever use of type famliies! In the typeclass declaration do the types have to be an actual `:: Type` or could they be `:: a`?

Comment: If `Thing` expects things other than types that would be a fine thing to do. Any kind can go to the right of `::` in a type family declaration.

Comment: Took me a bit of doing to adapt your suggestion to my code (mostly consisting of just doing what you said), but once I stopped faffing about it worked like a charm. Thanks!